# How to use unix comm command in Tcl?

Tags: tcl, diff, comm

I am trying to use Unix's comm command to compare two files in Tcl.

I tried the below to no avail:

```
exec bash -c {comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > only_in_file1}
exec {comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > only_in_file1}
```

It is one of the quick way that I know to do so but if there is a method in Tcl, I would like to be introduced. In general, I would need to compare two files and find unique lines in only one of the files when the two files are lines of text of 10~100K lines.

Comment: `comm` requires two files as argument and I think one of the two can be stdin, so you want `comm -23 file1 file2`. Standard Unix has only one stdin so you can't do something like `comm -23 - -` with any Unix command

Comment: Why does the method with `exec bash -c` not work for you? What error message do you get? (The use of `<(...)` appears reasonable.)

Comment: @DonalFellows How can you redirect two stdins to the same program and expect it to know the difference between them and treat them like files?

Comment: @barry, those aren't "stdins", they are [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)s -- `comm` sees them as files.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and knowledge sharing. I think it may be because I am trying to use it in EDA tool.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks. I did not know that. I use tcsh and thought bash was similar, but that's a pretty cool bash-specific feature. I'll leave my incorrect comment up just so your reply makes ense.

Answer (score 0):

Since your files are small by comparison with modern computer memories (and you're just looking for the lines in the first that aren't in the second), the simplest method of doing the filtering in pure Tcl is to hold the files in memory.

```
# Standard read-all-the-lines-of-a-file stanza
proc readLines {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f
    return [split $data "\n"]
}

# Read and sort (but the sort is unnecessary for this algorithm)
set lines1 [lsort [readLines file1]]

# Read and load into a dict's keys (i.e., an associative map); sort not needed
set d {}
foreach line [readLines file2] {
    dict set d $line "dummy"
}

# Write out the lines from file1 that aren't in the dictionary
set f [open only_in_file1 "w"]
foreach line $lines1 {
    if {![dict exists $d $line]} {
        puts $f $line
    }
}
close $f
```

This isn't exactly the method used by `comm`, but the logic it uses is more difficult to get right and requires both inputs to be sorted.

Comment: downvoting-- there's no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @barrycarter You want to use an inferior platform-specific solution, that's up to you.

Comment: OK, I'll remove my downvote if you edit (I can't otherwise), but if you suggest a pure TCL solution, you've already said what you're doing isn't ideal. If there is a TCL function to do this (and there surely is), I agree it's technically a better cross-platform solution.

Comment: "if you suggest a pure TCL solution, you've already said what you're doing isn't ideal" -- what? It sounds like you're saying "If there isn't already a builtin command to accomplish a task then you're using the wrong tool"

Comment: @glennjackman I think I dropped a word there. I meant: `an efficient pure TCL solution would be good, but you've acknowledged your pure TCL solution isn't efficient`. In other words, I was suggesting the OP find an existing TCL library that efficiently implements the `comm` command

Comment: I see. I don't read anything Donal is saying to mean his code is not _efficient_ (apart from commenting that sorting the first file is not required). Each file is read once, the comparison of lines uses a dict so lookups are extremely efficient (is it O(1)?). He admits it does not implement what comm does but this task does not really require that.

Answer (score 0):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is commonly used for this scenario: Invoking from Tcl looks like

```
exec awk {NR == FNR {f2[$0]; next} !($0 in f2)} file2 file1 > only_in_file1
```

That's a one-liner-external-tool version of Donal's suggestion.

But your bash solution *should* work:

```
$ cat file1
1        
2
3
4
5

$ cat file2
6
5
4
3

$ tclsh
% exec bash -c {comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)}
1
2
% exec awk {NR == FNR {f2[$0]; next} !($0 in f2)} file2 file1 
1
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the one liner suggestion. I think exec bash call is not working because I am using it in eda tool which uses Tcl.